# How can I force the Unity Editor to the Game View

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I force the unity editor to show the Game View, instead of my custom editor window on playmode?
I have the following code:

```
void Update(){
  if (EditorApplication.isPlaying)
  {
     FocusWindowIfItsOpen(Type.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView"));
  }
}
```

I've read that the above should change the focus of the window. However, I can't seem to find the correct Type for this Game View Window. Not even in de docs

Comment: You do understand that FocusWindowIfItsOpen  will only focus the key and mouse events to the Window? It does not bring the specified Windows type to forward or move the other Windows behind....

Comment: Then is it possible with another way?

Comment: It depends. What are you doing and why do you need this?

Answer (score 6):

For changing focus to GameView this helped me:

```
EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem("Window/General/Game");
```